# Measure download -> install conversions

Tags: google-analytics

I'm noticing a steep drop off rate from the number of people who visit my download page to the number that launch my app. Right now I'm using separate Google Analytics accounts to track this. The problem is I can't see if certain browsers are leading to lower install rates than others.

Is there a better way to track this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, except you use a tracker which stores the ip address. Then the programm can make a request to your server and you can enumerate the ips.

Also, maybe you should respect the privacy of your users and don't take the risk to get flagged as spyware if you do nasty things with the sensitve files of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using campaign tracking for your app - http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/android.html#android-market-tracking

In this way, you could have the link to your App contain campaign information that includes the browser they are using when accessing the app.